# How do I find the equivalent circuit of a compensated attenuator?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors

[image: Circuit]

I can not find the equivalent circuit due to the wire joining the middle of the resistor branch and the capacitor branch.

Comment: What form of equivalent circuit are you looking for?

Comment: It's just a voltage divider if you combine the R and C into the equivalent impedance Z

Comment: This is already a circuit are you looking for a Thevinin or Norton equivalent?

Comment: I can't envision an equivalent circuit that is simpler than what you presented. If you use Thevenin it's easy to find the equivalent series resistance, which will be another RC parallel circuit with R=R1//R2 and C=C1+C2. However, except for special cases, the equivalent voltage source will be frequency dependent (expression with "s" component). In cases like this, representing the circuit with a transfer function makes more sense. That's what I present in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have the following general circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqXVes.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, using KCL we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{in}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_1=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{in}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, using KVL we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

substituting \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_1+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{in}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Solving for the unknowns, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{V}_1=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{in}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

So, when we try to solve for the input resistance, \$\text{R}_\text{in}\$, we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{in}=\text{I}_\text{in}\cdot\text{R}_\text{in}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\cdot\text{R}_\text{in}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$

In order to solve for the voltage across the resistor \$\text{R}_4\$, we get:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}_4}=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag6$$

---

In your circuit, the resistors \$\text{R}_3\$ and \$\text{R}_4\$ are capacitors. So we can use Laplace transform in order to solve that. Because we know:

- $$\text{R}_3\space\to\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_4\space\to\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag8$$

So, we get:

$$\text{v}_{\text{R}_4}\left(\text{s}\right)\space\to\space\text{v}_{\text{C}_2}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\frac{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\right)}{\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{sC}_1}+\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{sC}_1}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\frac{\text{R}_1}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\right)}\tag9$$

> Notice that equation \$(9)\$ is in the 'complex' s-domain, so in order to transfer back to the time-domain you need to use the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Your formula is correct. I added a second reply with an alternative way of calculating it.

Answer (score 3):

A direct way to analyze this is to define \$Z_1\$ as the equivalent impedance of \$R_1\$ // \$C_1\$; and \$Z_2\$ as the equivalent impedance of \$R_2\$ // \$C_2\$. This leaves us with a simple impedance divider, where:

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{Z_2(s)}{Z_1(s)+Z_2(s)}
$$

Converting to admittance to simplify the calculation, we get the equivalent formula:

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{1}{\frac{Y_2(s)}{Y_1(s)}+1}
$$

where:

$$
Y_x=sC_x+\frac{1}{R_x}
$$

So, we get:

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{1}{\frac{sC_2+\frac{1}{R_2}}{sC_1+\frac{1}{R_1}}+1}
$$

What can be rewritten as:

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\frac{sR_1C_1+1}{sR_PC_P+1}
$$

or

$$
\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{C_1}{C_1+C_2}\frac{s+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}}{s+\frac{1}{R_PC_P}}
$$

where \$R_P\$ and \$C_P\$ are the equivalent parallel of \$R_1\$//\$R_2\$ and \$C_1\$//\$C_2\$ respectively:
$$
\frac{1}{R_P}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}
$$
$$
C_P=C_1+C_2
$$
Notice that this transfer function has one pole and one zero.

At DC (\$s=0\$), the gain is determined by the resistor divider defined by \$R_2\$ and \$R_1\$:

$$
\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
$$

At higher frequencies (above the greater between the zero and the pole frequencies), the gain is defined by the capacitor divider:

$$
\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{C_1}{C_1+C_2}
$$
This makes the Bode plot look something like this:

[image]

Or like this, depending on the component values:
[image]

This circuit is commonly used for compensation in oscilloscope probes. The idea is to have one variable component (typically \$C_2\$) properly tuned so that the frequency response becomes flat (\$f_{zero}=f_{pole}\$). In this case, \$R_2\$ and \$C_2\$ are the equivalent parallel of the external components combined with the input impedance of the scope.